# Customised video player full screen android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am creating a video player (using Android's VideoView) inside a library. 3rd party application will pass the layout to my library so that library creates video player and add it to the layout. As per the standard user experience when user turns mobile in landscape mode then my video player should automatically turn to full screen.

My problem area:

1. How my video player will know that orientation changed because `onConfigurationChanged()` is inside Activity? Though I can force 3rd party app to give the orientation change event to library but searching for alternative.
2. How do I set video view to full screen? I don't have the control of activity's parent layout.

Comment: What about a customized videoview ?

Comment: Definitely, We have to customise the video view. But how do we achieve these features even if we customise it. Any pointers ??

Comment: Even for SurfaceView, If I am getting layout from app to library then how do I set the full screen to the view ? AFAIK to make the view to full screen, we need to add view to the layout (probably parent layout) whose width/height is match_parent. And I don't have activities parent layout inside the library.